# What's wrong with this dtd syntax?

Tags: xml, dtd

Can't wrap my head around - why is `xmllint` complaining about this dtd syntax, specifically `et_snote` line. - what am I doing wrong here?

```
<!ELEMENT et_snote (is_required?, (#PCDATA | vis? | ri?)*) >
<!ELEMENT is_required ( #PCDATA ) >
```

I get this error:

```
schema.dtd:166: parser error : expected '>'
<!ELEMENT et_snote (is_required?, ( #PCDATA | vis? | ri? )+) >
```

This is the command I run:

```
xmllint --noout --nowarning --nonet --dtdvalid schema.dtd my.xml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared the type of `et_snote` as element content, which by definition [cannot have character data](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-element-content), either get rid of `#PCDATA` or change the type to mixed content.

Comment: I dont mind declaring as mixed content - bu how would I make sure that `is_required` tag is always a first element under `et_snote`?

Comment: You can't, if you want to specify an order you cannot allow character data. Wrap the character data in another element if you must.